# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly": In Podfile

Tags: firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I am using react-native to build an app, I get the below error when I do `pod install`.

**The below is the complete error.**

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In Podfile:
    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 12.4.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.4.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.4.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

Comment: it's looks like version mismatching in firebase/CoreOnly from pod file and nodemodule @react-native-firebase/app. so try to update your pod file use this cmd *pod install --repo-update*

Comment: @KathirpandianK, tried it but I get this error `- pod install has bug`

Comment: I am having this same problem.  Did you solve it?  I am usingL

Comment: I am having this same problem.  Did you solve it?  I am usingL

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I just ran `pod install --repo-update` in my ios folder and it worked for me.